# Limit Excel Formula Result Containting Numbers and Text to 2 Decimal Places

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following formula I am using in a profit and loss excel.

```
=IF('2015'!F5='2014'!F4,"No Change",IF('2015'!F5>'2014'!F4,"Profit: $",IF('2015'!F5<'2014'!F4,"Loss: $")))&'2015'!F5-'2014'!F4
```

This works fine in most cases, but sometimes it decides to spit out a ton of decimal places. Is there a way I can limit this output to 2 decimal points while still including the text? If not, the text can go, but ideally I would like to keep it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap a `Round()` around the numerical parts: `Round(f5,2)` will round to Two decimal places.

Edit: Per your comment, wrap `Text([],#,###.##)`. around your final result. If I read your formula correctly, you could use `Text(ROUND('2015'!F301-'2014'!F318,2),"#,##0.00")` I believe.

(Thanks @ScottCraner for text format)

Comment: I was attempting this, but kept getting an error when doing so. Then I realized I don't need to round the comparisons just the final result. Ended up with the following. `=IF('2015'!F301='2014'!F318,"No Change",IF('2015'!F301>'2014'!F318,"Profit: $",IF('2015'!F301<'2014'!F318,"Loss: $")))&ROUND('2015'!F301-'2014'!F318,2)`

Comment: Now after applying this to the whole workbook, some decimals are only showing 1 place. I am assuming this is due to that digit being a zero, but is there a way to have it show?

Comment: @Tempyr Go to number formats; set as 2 decimal places.

Comment: I tried formatting the cells, but since there is text included it does not seem to function as intended.

Comment: @Tempyr - I edited my comment, I think I got the format correctly. Let me know if that doesn't work. Basically, we're going to force Excel to treat the number part as a number with two decimals.  (I can't recall though if the `#` should be `0` to force the digits to show).

Answer (score 1):

You can use =VALUE("Text") to have Excel view your text string as a value, if it can be resolved into one. I use this when "Text" has been compiled on the fly, using &.

A bit like =INDIRECT("Text") resolves a text string into a range